# Running Spark App for v1 vs v2

Tags: apache-spark, jar, version, config, spark-submit

I'm trying to move from setting up my spark app from using Spark v1 to v2. In v1, I would use Spark Context and Spark Config to initialize. However, according to the latest documentation for Spark v2 (Quick Start guide) I should use Spark Session and it is suggested that the config is passed from cmd using spark-submit (all that I have referred to is shown near the bottom of this page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).

Below is my app, with the Spark Session stuff (v2) commented out, showing how I would run things for v1. If I run it like this, I get the error 'failed to initialize Spark Context'. Then, if I rearrange my commenting to run things for Spark Session (v2), and run it by packaging the app as a JAR and using spark-submit in cmd (as per the same guide as already cited above), I get the error: "Cannot load main class from JAR file:/C:/"

I am changing my SPARK_HOME variable to point to the correct versions, and I am changing to the appropriate version in the build file.

This is the app:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Pack {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Pack")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  /* val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PackTest").getOrCreate() */

  val logFile = "C:/Spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/README.md"

  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()
  /*  val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()  */

  val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
  val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
  println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")

  /* spark.stop() */
  }
 }
```

This is the sbt build file:

```
name := "Pack"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" /* 2.2.0 
when trying sparksession */

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1" /* 2.2.0 
when trying sparksession */
```

Comment: Try using %provided on the spark dependencies

Comment: The first part of the issue had a simple solution: make sure the folder that the app is in is defined as a src folder (Intellij). So that, sorts out the v1 approach. However, I am still getting the same "cannot load class..." error when trying to run using spark-submit on cmd.
...I also added % "provided" onto the spark dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. The solution to v1 is already mentioned in my comment.

For v2, I was following the quick start guide to the letter, except for this one thing:
It came down to moving the class into a src folder called 'scala' instead of 'scala-2.11' (Intellij).
I also ran a rebuild, but don't know if this had an effect.

Seems trivial, but it sorted out the issue.